# HTML tags are properly aligned but still seems to be messed up

Tags: html, css

All my HTML tags are properly aligned but when I hover its code in inspect element it seems messed up, however, the output is okay.
[image]

As shown in the image above. My 1st row i.e "Name" is inside the `div` `.b1` but when I hover that div in Developer Tools it does not Highlight my 1st row. the problem is same for every row `.b2, .b3, .b4`....

Here's my HTML

```
<div class="invoice-details">

    <div class="blank b1">
        <strong>Name</strong>
    <div><?php if(!empty($student_full_name)) echo $student_full_name; ?></div>
    </div>
    <div class="blank b2">
        <strong>Father Name</strong>
        <div><?php if(!empty($father_full_name)) echo $father_full_name; ?> </div>
    </div>
    <div class="blank b3">
        <div class="sb1">
            <strong>Mob No.</strong>
            <div><?php if(!empty($sphone_f)) echo $sphone_f; ?></div>
        </div>
        <div class="sb2">
            <strong>Reg. No.</strong>
            <div><?php if(!empty($regno)) echo $regno; ?></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="blank b4">
        <div class="sb1">
            <strong>From Month</strong>
            <div></div>
        </div>
        <div class="sb2">
            <strong>To Month</strong>
            <div></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="blank b5">
        <div class="sb1">
            <strong>Session</strong>
            <div><?php if(!empty($session)) echo $session; ?></div>
        </div>
        <div class="sb2">
            <strong>Class/Section</strong>
            <div><?php if(!empty($class)) echo $class; ?></div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="blank b6">
        <div class="sb1">
            <strong>Mode Of Payment</strong>
            <div></div>
        </div>
        <div class="sb2">
            <strong>Cheque/NEFT Number</strong>
            <div>N/A</div>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

Here is my CSS

```
 .blank div{
    border-bottom: 1px dotted #000;
    float: right;
    padding-left: 5px;
    height: 30px;
    padding-top: 10px;
    text-align: center;
}
.blank strong{
    float: left;
    height: 30px;
    padding-top: 10px;
}
.b1 strong{
    width: 5%;
}
.b1 div{
    width: 95%;
}

.b2 strong{
    width: 12%;
}
.b2 div{
    width: 88%;
}


.b3 .sb1, .b4 .sb1, .b5 .sb1{
    float: left;
    width: 50%;
    height: 30px;
    border: none;
    padding: 0;
    text-align: left;
}
.b3 .sb2, .b4 .sb2, .b5 .sb2{
    float: right;
    width: 49.5%;
    height: 30px;
    border: none;
    padding: 0;
    text-align: left;
}
.b3 .sb1 strong{
    width: 14%;
}
.b3 .sb1 div{
    width: 86%;
}
.b3 .sb2 strong{
    width: 14%;
}
.b3 .sb2 div{
    width: 86%;
}

.b4 .sb1 strong{
    width: 20%;
}
.b4 .sb1 div{
    width: 80%;
}
.b4 .sb2 strong{
    width: 18%;
}
.b4 .sb2 div{
    width: 82%;
}

.b5 .sb1 strong{
    width: 17%;
}
.b5 .sb1 div{
    width: 83%;
}
.b5 .sb2 strong{
    width: 25%;
}
.b5 .sb2 div{
    width: 75%;
}

.b5 .sb1, .b5 .sb2{
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```

Comment: The height of .b1, .b2, .b3 etc is 0. This is because the actual field is probably absolute positioned.

Comment: We can help better if you post your code.

Comment: Have you clicked the icon of the box with the cursor in it? That is required before the browser highlights the element on the page.

Comment: Please see my edited question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Danny H probably is right. But there may also have another issue. `.sb1` `.sb2` etc. inside of `.b1, .b2, .b3` etc. may having `float:left` or `float:right` on them. And generally an element having floating element inside it will not take any place and that's why will not have any height.

If it's float which prevent your `.b1, .b2` etc. to take height then you can simply solve this by adding these css:

```
    .b1:after, .b2:after, .b3:after, .b4:after, .b5:after{
        content: '';
        display: table;
        clear: both;
    }
```